# Laravel Eloquent eager loading not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

In my blog application there users can post articles and comments on there. When I go to any user profile http://eloquent-laravel.app/user/Name then I want to eagerly loaded all articles and comments of that certain user. Here's my code but it's not eagerly loading all articles and comments.

```
$user = \App\User::with(['articles', 'comments'])->where('name', $name)->first(); 
return view('articles.user', compact('user'));
```

User Model's code

```
public function articles() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
}

public function comments() 
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Comment::class, Article::class, 'user_id', 'article_id');
}
```

How can I eagerly loaded these articles and comments? 
But if i remove the where clause then eager loading is working. But I do need to get a certain user with all articles and comments eagerly loaded.
Thanks

Comment: Have you set the relationships correctly? Please share your models code.

Comment: What is the $user object returning, have you tried troubleshooting step by step?

Comment: User object is nicely returning all articles with comments, but not with eagerly loaded. It makes query for each articles and comments.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Okk try this.. in your Article model add

```
    public function comments() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

now from your controller or repository add

```
 $user = \App\User::with(['articles.comments' => function ($query)use($userId) {
        $query->where('user_id',$userId);
}])->where('name', $name)->get();
```

here you will get a particular user's all articles along with his comments only

in another situation(like you want all the comments and posts of a user) you can do this :
add this in User Model

```
public function comments() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

and then try

```
$user = \App\User::where('name', $name)->with(['articles', 'comments'])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$user = \App\User::where('name', $name)->with(['articles', 'comments'])->first();
```

Comment: Tried that too, but still not eagerly loading. 
Thanks

Comment: `$user = \App\User::where('name', 'LIKE',  '%'.$name.'%')->with(['articles', 'comments'])->first(); `